# Manipulate causing frequent crashes

Tags: manipulate

I am putting together a dynamic 3D plot which is to be "manipulated".  The code does what I want it to, but keeps crashing all the time.  Sometimes it crashes the kernel, so I just have to run the input cell again.  Other times, however, it completely crashes Mathematica.

The only potential problem I see is the fact that some of the dynamic variables are interdependent.

```
a = 3;
b = 3;
c = 12;
Manipulate[Graphics3D[
  (*First we evaluate all the vectors we need:*)Evaluate[
   Haxis = {2/(12398.434/e)*a, 0, 0}; hlength = Norm[Haxis];
   Kaxis = {0, 2/(12398.434/e)*b, 0}; klength = Norm[Kaxis];
   Laxis = {0, 0, 2/(12398.434/e)*c}; llength = Norm[Laxis];
   origin = {0, 0, 0};
   HKL = Haxis + Kaxis + Laxis;
   ewaldsphere = 
    ParametricPlot3D[
      HKL*{Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]}, {u, -π/2, π/
        2}, {v, -π/2, π/2}, Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, 
      Axes -> None, PlotStyle -> False][[1]];
   ewaldsphereradius = Norm[ewaldsphere];
   horizonsphere = 
    ParametricPlot3D[{{HKL/2*{Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]} + 
         Haxis/2},
       {HKL/2*{Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]} - 
         Haxis/2}}, {u, -π/2, π/2}, {v, -π/2, π/2}, 
      Mesh -> None, Boxed -> False, Axes -> None, 
      PlotStyle -> {GrayLevel[.1], GrayLevel[0.1]}][[1]];];
  {(*These are the vectors*)
   Black, Arrowheads[{-0.04, 0.04}],
   Arrow[Tube[{-Haxis, Haxis}*1.25, 0.01]],
   Arrow[Tube[{-Kaxis, Kaxis}*1.25, 0.01]],
   Arrowheads[0.04], Arrow[Tube[{origin, Laxis}*1.25, 0.01]],
   Opacity[0.1], ewaldsphere, Red, Opacity[0.8], horizonsphere,
   Red, Sphere[{x, y, z}, Norm[HKL]*0.01]
   },
  Boxed -> True, Axes -> True, AxesStyle -> Directive[Thick, Bold], 
  AxesLabel -> {H, K, L}, 
  FaceGrids -> {{0, 0, -1}, {-1, 0, 0}, {0, -1, 0}}, 
  FaceGridsStyle -> Directive[Orange, Dashed], ImageSize -> 400, 
  ViewPoint -> {0, 2, 0}, ViewCenter -> Automatic], {{e, 8000}, 400, 
  15000}, {{x, 0}, -hlength, hlength}, {{y, 0}, -klength, 
  klength}, {{z, 0}, 0, llength}]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which version and which platform?

Comment: I am using version 10 running on a Mac OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: The FE crashes on me (sometimes? frequently?) when I rotate 3D graphics (V10.0.1, Mac OSX 10.9.5)  `Manipulate` does not seem to be a factor.  (BTW, `ewaldsphereradius = Norm[ewaldsphere]` is unused as well as probably a mistake.)

Comment: Yes, very crash, much unstable!